# Facebook login not working in Laravel

Tags: facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-4

I want to create login module using facebook in Laravel using the below code but the issue is the session variable is blank and so it is not redirecting to the home page. After clicking on the Login button of facebook my program control moves to the following else part  `return Response::make('Not loggedin', 400);` and i see

jquery.min.js: 4 GET http://localhost/Script/login/fb 400 (Bad Request) in my browser console.

I am new to Laravel. Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

> UserController.php

```
public function loginWithFb() {


$redirectUrl = Input::get('redirect_url');
$facebookBaseConfig = Config::get('facebook');
$config = app('siteConfig');
$facebookConfig = $config['main']['social']['facebook'];
$facebookConfig['appId'] = empty($facebookConfig['appId']) ? '' : $facebookConfig['appId'];
$facebookConfig['secret'] = empty($facebookConfig['secret']) ? '' : $facebookConfig['secret'];
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($facebookConfig['appId'], $facebookConfig['secret']);
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
$session = null;

function getUserDataFromFb($session){
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
    return $graphObject;
}

try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}


if(Request::ajax()) {

    if ($session) {
      // Logged in.
        $uid = $session->getUserId();
        $accessToken = $session->getToken();
        $profile = Profile::whereUid($uid)->first();
        if (empty($profile)) {
            $me = getUserDataFromFb($session);  
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name'];
            $user->email = $me['email'];
            $user->photo = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture?type=large';

            $user->save();

            $profile = new Profile();
            $profile->uid = $uid;
            //$profile->username = $me['username']; //Username not available in the new Facebook API
            $profile->access_token = $accessToken;
            $profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);

        }
        else {
            $profile->access_token = $accessToken;
            $profile->save();
        }
        $user = $profile->user;
        Auth::login($user);
        return Response::json(array('user' => $user));
    } else {
        return Response::make('Not loggedin', 400);
    }
} else{
    if ($session) {
        if($redirectUrl) {
            return Redirect::to($redirectUrl);
        } else{
            return Redirect::route('home');
        }
    }
    return Redirect::route('login');
}
```

}

> View:

```
<script>
    (function(){
        window.loginWithFb = function(){
            FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log('Logged in as ' + response.name + '.');
                 });
               } else {
                 $('#loginError').removeClass('hide').html('<div class="alert alert-error">' + __('fbPermissionError') + '</div>');
               }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        }

        var body = $('body');
        body.on('click', '[data-action="loginWithFB"]', function(e){
            loginWithFb();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        body.on('loggedIn', function(){
            var loginModal = $('#loginModal');
            loginModal.modal('hide');
        });
        body.on('loggedIn:fb', function(){
            if(!User.isLoggedIn()) {
                var loginModal = $('#loginModal');
                loginModal.addClass("logging-in");
                $.get(BASE_PATH + '/login/fb').success(function(response){
                    User.setData(response.user);
                }).fail(function(response){
                    $('body').trigger('login:error', response);
                }).always(function(){
                    loginModal.removeClass("logging-in");
                });
            }
        });
        body.on('prompt-login', function(e, message){
            var loginModal = $('#loginModal');
            loginModal.find('.login-prompt-message').html(message);
            loginModal.modal('show');
        });
    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Are you aware that Laravel has a social network integration package?  https://github.com/laravel/socialite It can be used to easily integrate social logins with Laravel's Auth flow.

Comment: @Joe: I don't want to use Socialite because my project contain php sdk so i don't want to change it i have implemented seperate application just for testing purpose but i'm not getting user id. It is 0. Here is a link of question which i have asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478512/cannot-get-user-id-through-getuser-in-laravel-4-using-facebook-sdk. Please help to sort out my issue.